# Alinhar elementos em cima do outro html css

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, preciso alinhar os dois campos de data que estão abaixo com os dois campos de cima. Qual o melhor jeito de fazer isso?

[image: Foto]

Conforme a imagem, quando eu dou margin left auto no span ele não fica exatamente embaixo. Como que eu faria pra alinhar? Muito obrigado

```
                    <select id="slcGrafico" style="width:260px; " onchange="chgOpcaoGrafico()" class="browser-default custom-select">
                        <option value="1" selected>Comparar com o dia</option>
                        <option value="5">Comparação média</option>
                        <option value="2">Busca amostragem

                        <option value="3">Origem x Destino</option>
                        <option value="4">Estudante x Passe Livre</option>



                    </select>



                         <div style="display: flex;float: right;margin-left: 10px; " id="inputGrafico">
                             <input id="valorFiltroGrafico1" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                             <input id="valorFiltroGrafico2" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="margin-left:5px;height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                        </div>

                    <div style="display: flex;margin-top:3px; " class="row">



                        <span style="margin-left: auto;" >   

                            <input id="valorFiltroGrafico3" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                            <input id="valorFiltroGrafico4" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="margin-left:5px;height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                        </span>


                    </div>
```

Comment: porque não cria uma estrutura que coloque os elementos dentro de divs com as mesmas dimensões para que fiquem alinhados corretamente? assim por exemplo: https://pasteboard.co/JO0WSuO.png

Comment: Seria legal se você usasse as classes de grid do bootstrap pra manter o alinhamento que deseja ou também criar seu próprio grid.
Como fazer o grid: <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN1UjzRSdBk">Desvendando o CSS Grid na prática | Mayk Brito</a>

Answer (score 0):

O espaço entre os elementos(horizontal) é diferente, entre os elementos de baixo é maior que o de cima. Além disso você usou margin-left em uma div e na outra não, fiz alguns testes, veja se dessa forma funciona:

```
<select id="slcGrafico" style="width:260px; " onchange="chgOpcaoGrafico()" class="browser-default custom-select">
                    <option value="1" selected>Comparar com o dia</option>
                    <option value="5">Comparação média</option>
                    <option value="2">Busca amostragem

                    <option value="3">Origem x Destino</option>
                    <option value="4">Estudante x Passe Livre</option>



                </select>



                     <div style="display: flex;float: right;margin-left: 10px; " id="inputGrafico">
                         <input id="valorFiltroGrafico1" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                         <input id="valorFiltroGrafico2" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="margin-left:10px;height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                    </div>

                <div style="display: flex;float: right;margin-left: 10px;margin-top:3px; " class="row">



                    <span style="margin-left: 1473px;" >   

                        <input id="valorFiltroGrafico3" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                        <input id="valorFiltroGrafico4" type="date" value="2020-01-12" style="margin-left:5.5px;height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);">
                    </span>


                </div>
```

Com o margin-left:auto; do span, todos os elementos ficavam alinhados na horizontal.